# TranslateService couldn't translate Date string is incorrect

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx

I would like to display the label according to the user's local language,

1. I defined the strings file hardcode, it including a variable `permanentDate`, as below: `test.strings`:

   ```
   "FACTORY_BLOCK_START","PERMANENT_BLOCK","(If you choose Yes, Blocking End Date is automatically set to {{ permanentDate }}.)","","Permanent Block field for test form"
   ```
2. In the `test.model.json` file, set the label is:

   ```
   'FACTORY_BLOCK_START.PERMANENT_BLOCK', test.model.json file:
   {
     'section': null,
     'repeatableSection': null,
     'isCombo': null,
     'itemId': '2136',
     'answerType': 'YesNo',
     'label': 'FACTORY_BLOCK_START.PERMANENT_BLOCK'
     ...
   }
   ```
3. When rendering the page, I get the `test.model.json` label using the `.getTranslatedString()` method.

   ```
   private translate(matrixTemplate: SMQuestionnaire): SMQuestionnaire {
       const clonedMatrixTemplate: SMQuestionnaire = _.cloneDeep(matrixTemplate);

       _.map(clonedMatrixTemplate.items, (item) => {
           if (item.itemId === this.factoryBlockConstant.blockPermanentId) {
               const transformedLocal = this.dateTransformService.translateLocalDateFormat();
               const paramMap: { [key: string]: string } = {};
               paramMap['permanentDate'] = this.datePipe.transform(this.factoryBlockConstant.permanentDate, transformedLocal) as string;
               item.label = this.test.commonService.getTranslatedString(item.label, paramMap);
           } else {
               item.label = this.test.commonService.getTranslatedString(item.label);
           }
       });
       matrixTemplate = clonedMatrixTemplate;
       return matrixTemplate;
   }
   ```

`test.commonService.ts`:

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) {}

getTranslatedString(key: string, params?: any): string {
    let translateKey: string;
    this.translateService.get(key, params)
        .subscribe(translation => {
            translateKey = translation;
        });
    return translateKey;
}
```

Debugging the method: when invoking it, the key, and the params are correct:

[image: Invoke getTranslatedString method]

Expected result: The label should display Chinese formate for `permanentDate`: `如果您选择是，则冻结日期设置为 9999年12月31日。`.

Actually result: `如果您选择是，则冻结日期设置为 31/12/9999。`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/897

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: @KevinZhang Thanks your answer, Maybe it's different with that case. We didn't define the date in html file, it existed in json file, we will mapping the label by id then render the page, i doubt the method 'getTranslatedString' has some error, but i don't know what's the issue for this? you could find above screen shot (Invoke getTranslatedString method),thanks